# Mac Chrome Canary Command+[C]

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When I use Google Chrome Canary: Version 69.0.3453.3 (Official Build) canary (64-bit) (even in Incognito mode) on Mac OS X, and I push Command+[c],
Dev Tools appears and clipboard copying does not work.

When I use Google Chrome Stable: Version 67.0.3396.79 (Official Build) (64-bit), Command+[c] works normally.

How can I make Canary work normally?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug with the latest version of Canary.

Here's the official bug report: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=851257&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Comment: Thanks! The problem seems has been solved.